# select different element types with same super element class

Tags: jquery-selectors

Look at the following selector:

`#myClass a, #myClass span`

Is there a way to write this without specifying `#myClass` twice, like `#myClass (a, span)` ?

Comment: Since you're talking specifically about jQuery, maybe `$('#myClass').find('a, span')`?

Comment: I want to use it as a `globalSelector` attribute of a global `<p:tooltip />` tag in PrimeFaces, which uses jQuery in the background, so I cannot edit the jQuery-code myself.